# Unexpected FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, eclipse, filenotfoundexception

I have learned Java for about a month and am currently learning I/O of Java but I have encountered some problems. Below is a simply toy code to practice with the Inputstream.

```
import java.io.*;

public class IOTest{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
   InputStream in;
   in = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
   int total = 0;
   while (in.read() != -1)
   total++;
   System.out.println(total + " bytes");
   }
}
```

The above code compiles Okay. The purpose of this code is to simply calculate how many bytes in the arguments. However, when I run the compiled code with arguments, for example:

```
java IOTest firstTrial
```

The system gives the following Exception message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: firstTrial <The system 
cannot find the file specified>
       at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
       at java.io.FileInputStream.<init><Unknown Source>
       at java.io.FileInputStream.<init><Unknown Source>
       at IOTest.main<IOTest.java:8>
```

Please help point out how was the exception thrown?

**One extra question is I am using Eclipse for java programming. What is the End-of-Input character in Eclipse for Java? Thanks**

Comment: Ctrl+D for EOF/end of input

Comment: where firstTrial  file exist ?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't make myself understood. I was trying to read the arguments during running of the code and calculate the number of bytes in the arguments. In the example above, firtTrial is the argument I input during running the IOTest code.

Answer (score 0):

You are not reading a file:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: firstTrial <The system 
cannot find the file specified>
```

Put some full filepath as argument and your program will cont the bytes.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if you want to read the *argument string itself* as an `InputStream,` but the way `FileInputStream` works is that the `String` you pass it is not the *data* to read, but the *name of a file* to open and read.

However, you can read the string itself as data. You can do that with a `StringReader,` if you want to use the `Reader` API in Java, or if you want to read the raw bytes as an `InputStream` you can do that, too. (But you need to specify the character encoding. In this case, I am specifying it as "UTF-8".)

```
import java.io.*;

public class IOTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        byte[] bytes = args[0].getBytes("UTF-8");
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        int total = 0;
        while (in.read() != -1) {
            total++;
        }
        System.out.println(total + " bytes");
    }
}
```

Notice that I obtain the bytes from the string, and then use a `ByteArrayInputStream` instead of a `FileInputStream` to read them. I made one other change, which was to put braces around the `while` loop body. I prefer to either have loops on one line, or, better yet, to put braces around the body to make the extent of the loop clearer (and possibly avoid errors).